# How can I use the same compose.yml file be used locally and with azure?

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

Is there a best practice as to what to do when you need your compose.yaml file to have different values when running locally or when deploying to azure aci?

for example, I have a service that needs a volume to mount:
so locally i just add:

```
volumes:  
   my-data:
```

but when deploying to azure I need the my-data: volume to also include inside it:

```
volumes:  
   my-data:
      driver: azure_file
      driver_opts:
         share_name: my-share
         storage_account_name: my-storage-account
```

Any suggestions on how to make those two things work together?

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried to set up your requirements in my lab environment as below. It is working fine for me.**

In this demo, I have used **nginx** image in my docker-compose file and attached azure volume to store access log and error log files of nginx server.

I have followed below steps to repro.

**Step 1:** Create a **Storage account** in Azure and make a note below.
a. storage account name
b. file share name
c. storage account access key

**Step 2**: Create **docker compose** file like below.

[image]

**Code:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - acilogs:/var/log/nginx
      
volumes:
  acilogs:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      storage_account_name: <storage name>
      storage_account_key: <storage account key>
      share_name: <file share name>
```

**Step 3:** Create docker context as shown below.

a. `$docker login azure`
b. `$docker context create <context name>`
c. `$docker context use <context name>`
d. `$docker context ls` to see all the available contexts and current context (context marked with *).

[image]

Refer this document [Deploying Docker containers on Azure](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/) for more information on setting up docker context.

**Step 4:** Run **docker compose up**. It will create azure container instances in portal.

**Note: Make sure you are in correct docker context**.

[image]

Verify ACI created in portal.
[image]

[image]

You can also check mount files storage account.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your effort very much. However I don't see how this answers my Q:...  it does not talk at all about how to run said setup locally and how to handle the need to have the volumes: section of the compose.yaml file look differently when you want to run this setup locally...

Comment: @epeleg As, local volume cannot directly interact with Azure file share deployed on Azure environment. Unfortunately, You cannot use the same volume in a compose.yaml file to interacts with your Azure Cloud File share. As, an alternative you can add the Azure file share as a mount in your local machine by following this document:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows and then use it in your compose.yaml file.

Comment: I was not expecting to use the azure volume locally.  If I remove the  "driver_opts:" and "driver:" sections it works fine locally. my Q is how do i differentiate the "compose for azure" move from the "compose for local" without having to duplicate the compose.yaml file. so that what is common would be written only once.